# function with parallel iterations

Tags: parallelization, iteration

```
coprimesParallelIter[n_] := DistributeDefinitions[GCD];
ClearAll;
ParallelTable[If[GCD[i, n] == 1, i, Nothing], {i, 1, n - 1}] // 
  Flatten // DeleteCases[Nothing]
```

That function generates the list of coprimes less than n, but how can this list of coprimes be stored?  When I call the function there is no return value.

Comment: Your code doesn't align with your question, so this is confusing. You haven't defined `n`, so maybe that's why it's failing. Also, you don't actually use `coprimesParallelIter` anywhere, so it's not clear why that is included in your sample code. Are you sure you posted what you intended to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use a [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) and store the results in a symbol (note that [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) evaporates on its own)

```
coprimesParallelIter[n_] := (
  DistributeDefinitions[GCD];
  ParallelTable[
   If[GCD[i, n] == 1, i, Nothing],
   {i, 1, n - 1}])

list = coprimesParallelIter[20]

(* {1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19} *)

coprimesParallelIter2[n_] := (
  DistributeDefinitions[GCD];
  ParallelTable[
   If[CoprimeQ[n, i], i, Nothing],
   {i, 1, n - 1}])

list === coprimesParallelIter2[20]

(* True *)
```

Comment: oh, heh, the OP intended the whole thing to be the definition. Nice catch!